# Correlation of two normal distributions

Tags: regression, correlation, normal-distribution, population

I have a population $x$ with $\sigma/\mu=a$, and a second population $y$ with $\sigma/\mu=b$. The linear regression is $y=cx$. How would I find the correlation between $y$ and $x$, given that the populations are homoscedastic and normal?

If they were independent, I know the correlation would be zero, but I tried putting some sample data in Excel and got a numerical answer. What would be the general way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $y = cx$ should be
$$
\frac y {\sigma_Y} = \rho \frac x {\sigma_X} 
$$
which becomes
$$
\frac y {\mu a} = \rho \frac x {\mu b}.
$$
So
$$
c = \rho\frac a b.
$$
Thus $\rho = \dfrac{cb} a.$

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized that the correlation could be directly calculated from the regression in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you run a linear regression $y=cx+e$ (only one independent variable) and you obtain the $R^2$ coefficient, its square root $\sqrt{R^2}$ is equal to the absolute value of the sample correlation between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: --- or its negative!

Comment: Well, of course, it can be negative. The square root of the $R^2$ is the *absolute value* of the correlation.

Comment: Yes, can you edit your answer such?